Next.jsにてAuth.js（旧Next-Auth）を導入したいが、GoogleのOAuthを組み込むことができない

Next.jsを新たに立ち上げ（６月２０日時点で最新のバージョン、app router使用）、Auth.jsはbeta版をインストールしました。beta版については、公式サイトにてバージョン４からbeta版となったときに破壊的変更が行われたために、特段の理由がない場合はbeta版を推奨していたためです。
そこから、Next.js、Auth.jsの公式サイトに従い、トップページの真ん中にGoogleサインインのボタンを配置するだけのページを作成しました。

中心に”Signin with Google”とあるだけのページ
この”Signin with Google”ボタンを押したときに、１番上のエラーが面が表示されます。
google cloudでは、以下のように設定を行いました。
（一部ID等を隠しております。）

ディレクトリ構成やファイルは以下のように、公式ページそのままなはずです。







google chrome, microsoft edge, firefoxの3つのブラウザーで、拡張機能を切った状態でも発生しました。

他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？

承知いたしました。
ご教示いただき、ありがとうございます。

.env.localの値について、{}を外すと正常に動作しました。
